# How to fetch the tweets of a specific time span using R?

Tags: r, twitter, twitter-streaming-api, twitter-search

I am trying to fetch all the tweets for some terms and hashtag of a specific period of time. Let's say I would like to fetch tweets on Disaster from April 1, 2017, to April 20, 2017. I can fetch real time tweets using stream API using. Is there any way to fetch the past tweets?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What do you have so far? Are you using [rtweet](https://github.com/mkearney/rtweet/)?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I am using rtweet. Actually now I can fetch tweets of a specific time. But the problem is when I am trying to save the tweets into files is became encrypted.

tweets <- searchTwitter("iphone", n=100, lang="en", since="2014-08-20")
exportJson <- toJSON(tweets)
save(exportJson, file="export.json")

Like the above code. The export.json giving an encrypted output. I tried to use txt file and also just save directly without export. When I just check the output of tweets it showing tweets are there. Any clue? @alistaire